# Doppelgänger detected: support tag wiki excerpt

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-wiki

I just received the [tag editor badge](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/188/tag-editor) for the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag, [the tag wiki of which we can't edit anymore.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/edit-tag-wiki/58) Now [the tag excerpt](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1012/revisions), apparently written by this badp idiot, goofily mimics the body of the full shebang.

Can the support tag wiki excerpt be reverted to its default content?

> This tag is used to request help with the use of one of the Stack Exchange sites' features. Please check the FAQ first as your support problem may have already been covered. If not, try the search. Nothing? Try searching again, but with slightly different words. If all else fails, post your support question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default content is that value. Furthermore, that's also the value on [Meta Stack Overflow's support wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/support/info).

I know you asked only to revert it for the formatting wonkiness, but I found that the duplication in general was off-putting. So I [borrowed Seasoned Advice's wiki excerpt](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/support/info), and added a little more flavor. ♪

Comment: Once again, your superior ninja capabilities surprise me.